# Uploading file from iOS to MVC controller

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a very simple file upload method on my `MVC controller` which works very well when uploading images from the browsers on my PC.

**Uploading Code :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string encodedId)
```

However, if I try to upload an image from my `iPhone` I get error as

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values

I tried removing the parameters from the method and instead accessing the data from the Request object:

**Modified Code :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload()
  {
     var file = HttpContext.Request.Files[0];
     string encodedId = HttpContext.Request.Form["EncodedId"];
```

This results in the same error.

I cant't ascertain what the `iPhone` is sending to the server as I don't have any kind of development tools on my `iPhone`.

Comment: Can you not ask the people that have developed the iPhone code to tell you? What I've done in the past to upload files from iOS to .Net is send the image as a Bas64 string but define it as a byte array on the .Net side

Comment: Hi Flexicoder. Sorry I should have said that the image is being uploaded from the iOS Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

I name my File which i am sending as File and get it via following code.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("UploadAttachment")]
        public IHttpActionResult UploadAttachment()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile File = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Get("File") : null;

                if (File != null)
                {
                    Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
                    var Result = uploader.uploadToServer(File);
                    return Ok(Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("File is Required");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Zain, my problem is not necessarily the implementation of the method. It's that I can't get the method to trigger because of a routing issue.